# In search of open source alternative to Sharepoint

Tags: open-source, intranet, community

Looking for suggestions on a platform whether paid or open-source that would provide a intranet-like solution for document sharing, blog, events posting, etc.

Google Apps/Doc is not an option, needs to look somewhat professional and hosted on our domain. Any suggestions or recommendations would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by intranet-like? Should the blogs/events/documents all be only accessible to company personnel?

Comment: Correct, this site would need to be private, authentication required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It really depends upon what's important to you.

As far as the most Sharepoint-like solution goes, IMO Al Fresco is it (that's good to some, but bad to others... depends on what you need).

For publishing of documents, Drupal and Joomla would be a better choice, and they can be extended very well with plugins provided by their large and active communities.

If your need is tied to business process management -- such as oversight on active projects, then a product such as Active Collab would be a better fit. It's not very Sharepoint like, but many people try to build things in Sharepoint that are ready to roll in other off-the-shelf solutions.

Good luck. Have fun checking out these various solutions!

Answer (score 6):

You might want to try [Knowledgetree](http://bitnami.org/stack/knowledgetree), [Liferay](http://bitnami.org/stack/liferay) or [Alfresco](http://bitnami.org/stack/alfresco). Depends on your needs, but could even be good idea to use [Redmine](http://bitnami.org/stack/redmine), Drupal, or Joomla. It quite depends on the case, people to maintain it, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Open Atrium
Drupal
Alfresco
Acquia Drupal Commons
acquia.com/products-services/drupal-commons

Answer (score 1):

Alfresco or Nuxeo are probably the two open source projects closest to Sharepoint. I tend to particularly like Alfresco (we package it as a free download for [BitNami](http://bitnami.org/stack/alfresco)) because of the out of the box network drive integration for Windows clients (it can be a bit tricky to configure though)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need the alternative. Anyway, as I know IBM-Websphere is java based solution which is an alternative for SharePoint.

Comment: We need an alternative since our team of developers are LAMP/Open-Source oriented. Thanks though!

Comment: I'm not sure Websphere is comparable to SharePoint.